# How can I sum of all element in vector?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I wanna input numbers of shapes and sum of area of shapes.

First line of input is how many shapes you want to calculate and after first line, you may input the types of shape, and size of shape.

But i have a problem with calculate with area of triangle and rectangle except circle.  only area of circle is well calculated..

```
$ ./a.out
1
R 2.0 1.0
0.00

$ ./a.out
1
T 2.0
0.00

$ ./a.out
1
C 1.0
3.14
```

I think problem comes from

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        sum += collection[i]->area(collection);
    }
```

this code! I think my area function only calculate first element of vector.....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Shape{
protected:
    int _r;
    int _w;
    int _h;

public:
    Shape(double r) : _r(r) {}
    Shape(double w, double h) : _w(w), _h(h) {}
    virtual double area(vector<Shape *>) = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape{
public:
    Circle(double r) : Shape(r) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return _r*_r*atan(1)*4.0; }
};

class Triangle : public Shape{
public:
    Triangle(double s) : Shape(s) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return sqrt(3) * pow(_r, 2) / 4; }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape{
public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h) :Shape(w, h) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return  _w * _h ;}
};

int main()
{

    int n;
    char info;
    int value;
    int value2;
    double sum;
    vector<Shape*> collection;
    vector<int> answer;

    sum = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        cin >> info;
        if (info == 'C')
        {
            cin >> value;
            Circle c(value);
            collection.push_back(&c);
        }
        else if (info == 'R')
        {
            cin >> value;
            cin >> value2;
            Rectangle r(value, value2);
            collection.push_back(&r);
        }
        else
        {
            cin >> value;
            Triangle t(value);
            collection.push_back(&t);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1 ; i++)
    {
        sum += collection[i] -> area(collection);
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code [doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/o4r9ooj5e). You can't push back `area` since it's a function not `Shape*`.

Comment: I think it would be compiled!! I edit!

Comment: Try to push a copy of `Shape` instead of a pointer. Since all your input are out of scope after `push_back`.

Comment: It's still strange, why do you need the whole collection to calculate a `Shape`'s area?

Comment: You create the shape, push it's address into the vector and when you reach the end of the scope your object gets destroyed but the address stays the same within your vector, pointing to garbage. That's known as a dangling pointer.

Comment: @LouisGo: `Shape` is pure virtual and therefore `std::vector<Shape>` is invalid.

Comment: there's already [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of interesting errors:

1. I have no idea why you're passing a `vector<Shape *>` to the `area()` method.
2. I don't understand why you are iterating from `0 .. n+1`. It doesn't match the input you provided.
3. As noted in the comments, you are continuing to reference a pointer to an object that has gone out of scope. Using the heap is a simple way to resolve this. Using a `unique_ptr` also ensures that the memory will be cleaned up.
4. Since you are using inheritance, it is good practice to make the base class have a virtual destructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Shape{
  protected:
    int _r;
    int _w;
    int _h;

  public:
    Shape(double r) : _r(r) {}
    Shape(double w, double h) : _w(w), _h(h) {}
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    virtual double area() = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape{
  public:
    Circle(double r) : Shape(r) {}
    double area() { return _r*_r*atan(1)*4.0; }
};

class Triangle : public Shape{
  public:
    Triangle(double s) : Shape(s) {}
    double area() { return sqrt(3) * pow(_r, 2) / 4; }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape{
  public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h) :Shape(w, h) {}
    double area() { return  _w * _h ;}
};

int main() {
    int n;
    char info;
    int value;
    int value2;
    double sum = 0
    vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> collection;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> info;
        if (info == 'C')
        {
            cin >> value;
            collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Circle>(value));
        }
        else if (info == 'R')
        {
            cin >> value;
            cin >> value2;
            collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Rectangle>(value, value2));
        }
        else
        {
            cin >> value;
            collection.push_back(std::make_unique<Triangle>(value));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += collection[i]->area();
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: 1 . I have no idea why you're passing a vector<Shape *> to the area() method.
-> because I wanna make method which of parameter
is vector<shape *> that calculate all sums of area .

Comment: 2. I don't understand why you are iterating from 0 .. n+1. It doesn't match the input you provided.
-> I think so. but in acually, my first line input require n+1. For example, if I input 2 in first line, my program only consider one shape, not two numbers of shape

Comment: 3.As noted in the comments, you are continuing to reference a pointer to an object that has gone out of scope. Using the heap is a simple way to resolve this. Using a unique_ptr also ensures that the memory will be cleaned up. -> I want to use but, my compiler show error. Does your compiler do well on this cord??